# Does findAndModify effectively lock the document to prevent update conflicts?

Tags: mongodb, locking, document

What type of locking does findAndModify() offer? Is is a write lock only, or read/write? Does it prevent simultaneous updates on the same record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the MongoDB docs for [MongoDB: findAndModify()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) for under [MongoDB: Atomic Operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations#AtomicOperations-FindandModify%28orRemove%29) it should be.

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB has a global (per-instance) write lock, which serializes all updates across all data in the server (though different servers in a sharded cluster will each have their own independent locks). This means that at any given instant in time, only one update is taking place on any document, and therefore only one update for any given document.

`findAndModify` doesn't do anything different in this regard than an ordinary `update` -- it just returns the document to you.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to interpret the explicit atomicity claims in the docs as a guarantee of future semantics (a contract to their future userbase) while (hearsay)  comments about the existing semantics of update or other operations which lack such promises should viewed as implementation details which should NOT be relied upon in quality code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what part of my answer -- if any -- this is in reference to. But the atomic update semantics are guaranteed both for `findAndModify` and ordinary `update`. The implementation (currently, a global write lock) may change, but the semantics will remain.